# Visual Studio 2022 getting error when creating "Angular and ASP.NET Core" project

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have a problem creating a project with Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise on Windows 10.

I try to create a project with the template "Angular and ASP.NET Core".

I don't change the default options (.NET 8.0, ...). When creating the project I get the message "The version of Angular CLI was not valid." The template tries to call `ng version` from the project directory calling `c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd`

At home (using Visual Studio Community) all works well - The ASP.NET Core server project gets created, and also the Angular client project.
At work (using Visual Studio Enterprise) I get this weird error directly after creating the project. The ASP.NET Core server projects gets created, the client project is completely empty.

I am able to call `ng version` from command line getting the expected result: `Angular CLI: 17.3.2, Node: 20.11.1, npm 10.2.4.`

I added some log `echos` to `ng.cmd` to make sure the right `ng.cmd` was called.
I uninstalled all components (Angular, Node.js), reinstalled them.
I uninstalled Visual Studio Enterprise, installed Visual Studio Community.
I tried to install other versions of angular/cli (e.g. 17.1.0).
Nothing changed the behavior.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks and best regards
Andy